# Avoiding Thread.sleep() but need to wait for some seconds even if the target element is visible and page is fully loaded

Tags: java, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I am testing some ajax search functionality. It goes like this, I search a term, a loader appears and after that results are displayed. After that browser closes. What happens is that if I run the following function in my test,

```
public void kenshoSearch(String searchTerm)
{
    driver.findElement(kenshoSearchBox).sendKeys(searchTerm);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(kenshoSearchVerify));
    //Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Results Verified");
}
```

It passes fine, but it closes after a split second once target element is located. What I want is to wait for 3 seconds after results are displayed. I can achieve that if I uncomment `Thread.sleep(3000)`, but I want to avoid that.

Is there any other way to stop the execution after the steps are performed correctly. Thanks

Comment: Why you don't like to use the standard function Thread.sleep to sleep your thread? Is there any

Comment: Why wait 3 seconds if you've already verified everything you need in the search results?

Comment: You can usually schedule a timer or timer task then have it execute code 3 seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser is closed automatically, there is no other way to do that. You will have to stick to `Thread.sleep()`